# How do I validate one post per day?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cron

I am trying to create a validation to ensure one post per day, 24hrs starting from 00:00. How can this be done in Rails please?

I did the following but I am not sure where to put the `today` method. Simpler alternatives are much appreciated.

```
def today
  where(:created_at => (Time.now.beginning_of_day..Time.now))
end
```

I then added a validation to the article model:

```
validate :time_limit, :on => :create
```

and defined `time_limit` in the same model like so:

```
def time_limit
 if user.articles.today.count >= 1
 errors.add(:base, "Exceeds daily limit")
end
```

But I Keep getting a "no method" error in the create action.

```
undefined method `today'
```

I'm not really sure where to put this method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shoud use scopes for that:

```
class Article
  scope :today, -> { where(:created_at => (Time.now.beginning_of_day..Time.now.end_of_day)) }
end
```

http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/NamedScope/ClassMethods/scope

Comment: I suggest to check if a post was created for full day not only from midnight till now. This way scope may be reusable (like - post for the day)

Comment: Sorry can you explain that a bit further ? I don't really understand what you mean.

Comment: @Joshua if you are asking Michael, I've already applied his suggestion. He meant that better to use Time.now.end_of_day instead of Time.now. That way you can re-use this scope in other cases.

Comment: @Joshua If you have set TimeZone in application.rb, then use Time.zone.now instead of Time.now

Comment: I am a bit confused as too what does what, I want 00:00 to start according to the users timezone. Which do i use ?

Comment: If you are setting user time zone with `Time.zone = 'some zone'`, then you should use Time.zone.now

Answer (score 0):

That error is because `today` is instance method of model, not a scope.

What you need is `scope`:

```
 scope :today, lambda{ where(:created_at => (Time.now.beginning_of_day..Time.now)) }
```