# How to limit a model to one record per day (Rails)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, limit

I would like to build a simple app where the user tracks how far he has run each day. I want it to be so that there is only one model entry per day. How do I limit the model to only allow one entry per day? I found a solution that suggests doing the following for a journal with unique daily journals:

```
add_index :journal_entries, [:user_id, :created_on], unique: true
```

However, I don't fully understand how to implement this. Do I have to have another model for this index?

Thank you!

Comment: There are probably a number of ways to do this technically, but I suggest starting at the user first and think about how you want it to work for them, at the user interface level. For example, do you want them to be able to make an entry at any time during the day as long as it's no more than one per day? Etc. Then work from the outside in rather than the inside out and make your implementation choices based upon that. You should be able to enforce whatever you want from the model, and present however you like from the view.

Comment: I would like for the user to be able to make an entry at any time during the day. Once they have made that entry, I would like for the element in the view to disappear. How would you recommend I go about this? Perhaps like this solution? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17776245/how-do-i-validate-one-post-per-day

Answer (score 4):

You probably want to do this from the controller, what I would recommend is when the user tries to enter an entry, you use `first_or_create!`.

```
@entry = Entry.where(created_at: Time.now.beginning_of_day.utc..Time.now.end_of_day.utc).first_or_create!
@entry.update_attributes(entry_params)
```

The above code finds an entry created within the current date, or creates one if it does not exist.