# How can I scope created_at between two times and use said scope on an instance?

Tags: class, ruby-on-rails-4, methods, scope, instance

I'm trying to create a scope, active, that queries for entries of a class, Shift, that are 5 hours old. I'm then trying to take the scope and apply it to an instance of Shift so I can have the shifts controller redirect to show the active shift. Here's shift.rb:

```
class Shift < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :active, -> { where(created_at: (Time.now.ago(5.hours)..Time.now)) }
  validates        :created_at, uniqueness: true
  validates_time   :created_at, :between => ['9:30pm', '2:30am']
  validate         :active_shift_limit
private
  def active_shift_limit
    if Shift.active.count >= 1
    errors.add(:base, "Shift already exists for tonight")
    end
  end
end
```

First off, I'm having problems with the scope. I created a shift 8 hours ago and am querying for it in the console.

```
Shift.active.exists?
Shift Exists (0.2ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "shifts" WHERE ("shifts"."created_at" BETWEEN '2015-09-14 22:48:35.929658' AND '2015-09-15 03:48:35.929768') LIMIT 1
 => true
```

So I take a look at the entry.

```
Shift.active
Shift Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "shifts".* FROM "shifts" WHERE ("shifts"."created_at" BETWEEN '2015-09-14 23:03:38.195154' AND '2015-09-15 04:03:38.195191')
 => #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Shift id: 32, shift_id: nil, vehicle_id: nil, user_id: nil, created_at: "2015-09-15 00:11:32", updated_at: "2015-09-15 00:11:32">]>
```

The scope is registering a range into tomorrow, I don't know why, so I try entering the range I've given the scope into the console to see if the problem is there:

```
Time.now.ago(5.hours)..Time.now
 => 2015-09-14 16:08:35 -0700..2015-09-14 21:08:35 -0700
```

Alright. At this point I'm stumped. Where am I going wrong?
As for the second part of the question, calling the scope on an instance of Shift, I'm also stumped. I've realized, after some tinkering, that scope is a class method. So I figured calling it on the method and putting that inside an instance variable would work. No cigar. I get this error:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in ShiftsController#create
"Couldn't find Shift without an ID"
```

Here's my shifts_controller.rb:

```
class ShiftsController < ApplicationController
  skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token, :only => :create
  def show
    @shift = Shift.find(params[:id])
  end
  def create
    @active_shift = Shift.active
    if Shift.active.exists?
      redirect_to shift_path(@active_shift)
    else
      @shift = Shift.new
      @shift.save
      redirect_to shift_path(@shift)
    end
  end
end
```

I'm using this gem for validates_time in shift.rb:
`gem 'jc-validates_timeliness', '~> 3.1.1'`. I heavily referenced this in figuring out the scope: [How do I validate one post per day?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17776245/how-do-i-validate-one-post-per-day)

Comment: Try `@active_shift = Shift.active.first`

Comment: Alright, this is what it gives me: `ActionController::UrlGenerationError in ShiftsController#create
No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"shifts", :id=>nil} missing required keys: [:id] `